# I want to use `kable` to print a table from the result of sapply

Tags: r

I want to display my output in markdown as a table and wanted to use the `kable` to stylize my output.

So this is what I have saved as `a`

```
a <- sapply(storm[,c("evtype", "fatalities", "injuries", "propdmg","cropdmg")], function(x) table(is.na(x)))
```

Which look like this in the console:

```
a
    evtype.FALSE fatalities.FALSE   injuries.FALSE    propdmg.FALSE 
          902297           902297           902297           902297 
   cropdmg.FALSE 
          902297
```

Presume I don't want to change the names how can I use `kable(x)`.  I read that x has to be a matrix or dataframe and tried `as.data.frame`, here is what the output looked like

```
 kable(as.data.frame(a))
[1] "|                 |      a|" "|:----------------|------:|"
[3] "|evtype.FALSE     | 902297|" "|fatalities.FALSE | 902297|"
[5] "|injuries.FALSE   | 902297|" "|propdmg.FALSE    | 902297|"
[7] "|cropdmg.FALSE    | 902297|"
attr(,"format")
.
.
```

I see that "a" is coming in as an entry 
I have also tried the arguments like `ncol=5, byrow =F` but I am gonna have to move on at this point and was hoping to get some pointers on how to think about this one.  Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for? How are the results not what you want? If you want a horizontal arrangement, make your data look like that, e.g. `knitr::kable(data.frame(lapply(mtcars, mean)))`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for actually.  I didn't realize that the output from `lapply` would do the trick.

Comment: Could you verify that: `lapply` horizontal output, `sapply` vertical.. yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kable(a)` should do it.

```
> a <- sapply(iris, function(x) table(is.na(x), useNA = "always"))
> kable(a)


|      | Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width| Species|
|:-----|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|-------:|
|FALSE |          150|         150|          150|         150|     150|
|NA    |            0|           0|            0|           0|       0|
```

Also note that you probably want the useNA = FALSE argument to `table()` or else your single unnamed row  is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your output, `useNA` let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem (even with my own data, since you didn't post yours). But this is what I'm able to see:

```
out <- sapply(split(iris, iris$Species), function(a) table(is.na(a)))
out
#     setosa.FALSE versicolor.FALSE  virginica.FALSE 
#              250              250              250 

library(knitr)
kable(as.data.frame(out))
# |                 | out|
# |:----------------|---:|
# |setosa.FALSE     | 250|
# |versicolor.FALSE | 250|
# |virginica.FALSE  | 250|
```

It's formatted as a latex table, not as character strings. But perhaps there's an option you've set or something else you're not showing us.

However, some options:

```
kable(data.frame(Species = names(out), Rows = unlist(out)), row.names = FALSE)
# |Species          | Rows|
# |:----------------|----:|
# |setosa.FALSE     |  250|
# |versicolor.FALSE |  250|
# |virginica.FALSE  |  250|
```

(That fixed the header over the row names.) Alternatively:

```
data.frame(Species = names(out), Rows = unlist(out)) %>%
  spread(Species, Rows) %>%
  kable()
# | setosa.FALSE| versicolor.FALSE| virginica.FALSE|
# |------------:|----------------:|---------------:|
# |          250|              250|             250|
```

I would generally believe, though, that you'd want to use the original labels (e.g. `setosa`), not `setosa.FALSE`. Regardless, if these don't fit your needs, please clarify your expected output.

Comment: sorry about that.  Thanks for your effort, let me try your ideas.

Comment: That's Markdown, not LaTeX.

Comment: Wasn't that the intent?